# Firefox not clearing last image loaded on Jquery popup overlay

Tags: jquery, css, image, firefox, modal-dialog

On [my site](http://www.t-grubbs.com/) I am using [jQuery Popup Overlay](http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/) to load my images on click through a stand alone overlay.

On Chrome, Safari, and Opera, un-cached stand alone images load and close just fine.  However, with Firefox, after I close a loaded image from the stand alone and open another un-cached image, the previous stand alone image appears until the new image is loaded.

HTML image snippet:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-md-1-1 pure-u-lg-1 l-box">
                <figure>1.</figure><a class="initialism standalone_open btn btn-success" href="#"><img class="pure-img" data-fullsize="images/full-size/darron.jpg" src="images/thumbs/darron-large.jpg" alt="Darron"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-2 l-box">
                <figure>2.</figure><a class="initialism standalone_open btn btn-success" href="#"><img class="pure-img" data-fullsize="images/full-size/tree.jpg" src="images/thumbs/tree-small.jpg" alt="Tree"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="standalone">
    <div class="overlay-control-container">
        <figure></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-image-container">
        <img class="pure-img">
    </div>
</div>
```

The pure-* classes are for responsive images/grids from PureCSS.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#standalone').popup({
  color: 'white',
  opacity: 1,
  transition: '0.3s',
  scrolllock: false,
  closeelement: '#standalone',
});

$(".pure-g img" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
var currentSrc= $(this).data("fullsize");
$("#standalone img").attr("src", currentSrc);
});

});
```

I am not sure what is causing this.

EDIT:

Solved using the `.removeAttr()` method.

The correct JS should be:

```
$(".pure-g img" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
var currentSrc= $(this).data("fullsize");
$("#standalone img").removeAttr("src", currentSrc).attr("src", currentSrc);
});
```

Comment: I see you are new here. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Welcome to StackOverflow! Hours of fun! ;)

Comment: any joy with the latest update?  https://jsfiddle.net/snr80o4r/

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved easily by adding one line of code

```
var currentSrc= "";
```

before setting the source of the picture (var currentSrc) equal to `$(this).data("fullsize);`

so your function would be like so

```
$(".pure-g .pure-img" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    var currentSrc= "";
    currentSrc= $(this).data("fullsize");
    $("#standalone img").attr("src", currentSrc);
});
```

see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/knucgzbc/1/)

EDIT:

A strange workaround, this, but I reproduced the error (eventually) on my phone and was able to solve it by doing the following

```
$(".pure-g .pure-img" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    var currentSrc= null;
    currentSrc=" "; //doesn't work if you omit either of the first 2 lines
    currentSrc= $(this).data("fullsize");
    $("#standalone img").attr("src", currentSrc);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Rachel--thank you for your assistance.  I still seem to be getting the same behavior with FF with the new code added.  What I am seeing on your fiddle with: [Firefox] (http://i.imgur.com/ewQaGB2.gifv), [Chrome] (http://i.imgur.com/QCAUtD2.gifv)

Comment: @tdgrubbs i have vsn 46 (currently upgrading to 47) but the vsn shouldn't matter. There is a small error in the fiddle; currentSrc is being declared twice as a var. Remove the 'var' on the second line, and it should be ok. see here https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/knucgzbc/1/

Comment: having said that, you should always keep a current vsn of your browser (btw even FF 46 only has 4.87% global usage, vsn 47 is 0.17%(!) according to caniuse.com)

Comment: still showing the same behavior.  On vsn 47, but exhibited with vsn 46 as well for me.  Strange...I'm on a Mac, so I could try another laptop at some point....though not sure this would make a difference.  Did you see the same behavior before you implemented the var currentSrc= "";?

Comment: No, I didn't. Mac vsns are different I think. Check the number again

Comment: Did you clear your cache before trying the new fiddle? That would've been an idea..

Comment: @tdgrubbs the solution is to set the src to null first. I saw the behaviour in my phone. Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3j2ax5Lm/2/ my phone is android but hopefully it'll work on Mac too.

Comment: Only tested in phone, not desktop

Comment: strangely enough I'm still seeing it on your newest fiddle with both android and desktop FF.  I clear my cache each time just in case.

Comment: That is strange! Works perfectly for me, do you have latest vsn of browser? Could there be other files conflicting with it?

Comment: Are you getting errors in your console? I'm making dinner, so haven't had a chance to test it on laptop.

Comment: I have the latest vsn (47.0.1).  I will test on a PC when I can and get back.

Comment: Any errors? Press f12 to see console. I have 47.01 too

Comment: Bear in mind that you've been accessing your site for a lot longer than I have, so you may have to clear your cache for a few months as opposed to a day or week...

Comment: @tdgrubbs i found 2 minor errors, one was that you omitted your 'i' in your for loop, another was that there was a comma where there was supposed to be a semi-colon. try this https://jsfiddle.net/rc2bf789/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/snr80o4r/ (same)

Comment: no luck :(  still displaying same behavior on the newest fiddle.

Comment: Suggestion: go onto another machine and try the link. I'm pretty sure it works. It resolved the issue in my offending android phone and it works fine on my Nexus too. My sis and dad have Macs. Will send the link to them for testing.

Comment: I don't have access to another machine at the moment but I will certainly update you when I get the opportunity :)

Comment: @tdgrubbs the recommended procedure according to jquery docs is to use .removeData to completely clear the data before loading new data. I have taken the liberty of hosting a page (not a fiddle) on my site with this code. I hope it will help you. There is a miniscule delay, but its quick, and follows guidelines. The url is http://rachelgallen.com/tdgrubbs1.html

Comment: @tdgrubbs i think this one is slightly better http://rachelgallen.com/tdgrubbs/tdgrubbs01.html

Comment: thanks for trying that out, but it's still being stubborn with un-cached images on FF, unfortunately.  I won't have access to a PC for a few days to check.  Was the behavior replicated on your family's macs?

Comment: @tdgrubbs when I loaded it as a page it was reproducible. It was to much less effect in the later page that I posted.

Comment: There are quite a few errors in your CSS, which might not help. Fix those. There's also 2 errors (which I couldn't pinpoint) in the included js files. I posted my own js into jsbin though and it showed no errors. So it's in another file. Maybe if you fixed these, you'd have more success.

Comment: I believe I solved it.  Take a look at my edit.  Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/snr80o4r/19/

Comment: @tdgrubbs good call. but you should really use .prop instead of .attr

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on .prop().  As .prop returns FF to the initial nasty behavior, I added an IE check to the code at https://jsfiddle.net/snr80o4r/20/.  Before I update my edit, would you mind checking it's behavior on IE as well, since I don't have access to it on a mac.

Comment: @tdgrubbs hmm, i didn't realise i was now a personal slave! I realised after that using prop, while generally recommended, would've been a mistake in this case, and is pointed out as such in the API. in IE, 20 doesn't work, but 19 does. I hope i get a vote out of this!

Comment: I am unable to upvote until I have 15 reputation.  edit: it looks like it counts, just not publicly until 15.

Comment: Yes I know. You may have more questions! Also you gain rep when you accept answers.

Comment: I see...so with more (separate) questions in the future I'll gain rep with accepted answers, then I could come back and vote yours up publicly?

Comment: Yes, you could. I did spend a while on this q so it would be appreciated :) you also gain rep when people upvote your questions or if you answer a question and it gets upvoted or/and accepted

Comment: Definitely!  I was planning on it.  I appreciate your time, it definitely steered me in the right direction.

Comment: @tdgrubbs you're welcome. Just had a look at your other q. Weird! Is there no moz media queries in purecss? I'm sure you could probably add your own..